# How to add texbox and text in ppt using twapi

Tags: com, tcl, powerpoint

Good morning ,
Can any one assist how to get textbox and text in power point presentation using twapi.
and where can I find user manual related to the twapi power point related commands.
 Regards

Comment: It's going to be using COM to talk to Powerpoint, but that's something where I don't know much.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for response.i need command Syntex for adding text box in ppt.